# Getting an npm permissions error in CI/CD after upgrading to Node v16 - working fine locally running container from same image

Tags: docker, npm, github-actions, eslint, file-permissions

After upgrading from Node `14.15` => `16.18.1`, I have started getting a `Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'` error when trying to run ESLint in the GitHub Actions CI/CD workflow.

Note: I am running this inside a Docker container.  I am able to run the ESLint script locally in a container built from the same image, but when running in Github Actions, the workflow fails with the following error:

```bash
Creating csps-lint ... done
Attaching to csps-lint
csps-lint    | 
csps-lint    | > lint
csps-lint    | > bash ./scripts/lint.sh
csps-lint    | 
csps-lint    | Running Prettier to identify code formatting issues...
csps-lint    | 
csps-lint    | Checking formatting...
csps-lint    | All matched files use Prettier code style!
csps-lint    | 
csps-lint    | Running ESLint to identify code quality issues...
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile  error cleaning log files [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile   errno: -13,
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile   code: 'EACCES',
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile   syscall: 'scandir',
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile   path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
csps-lint    | npm WARN logfile }
csps-lint    | npm ERR! code EACCES
csps-lint    | npm ERR! syscall mkdir
csps-lint    | npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp
csps-lint    | npm ERR! errno -13
csps-lint    | npm ERR! 
csps-lint    | npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
csps-lint    | npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
csps-lint    | npm ERR! 
csps-lint    | npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
csps-lint    | npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1001:123 "/root/.npm"
csps-lint    | 
csps-lint    | npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /root/.npm/_logs
csps-lint    | npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
csps-lint    | ESLint found code quality issues. Please address any errors above and try again.
csps-lint    | 
csps-lint exited with code 1
1
Aborting on container exit...
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My GH Actions workflow is this:

```yaml
name: test-eslint-fix
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - eslint-fix
jobs:
  login:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
  linting:
    needs: login
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: LINT_COMMAND=lint docker-compose -f docker-comp-lint.yml up --abort-on-container-
```

Here is the Dockerfile that the image is created from:

```
# start FROM a base layer of node v16.18.1
FROM node:16.18.1

# confirm installation
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v

# Globally install webpack in the container for webpack dev server
RUN npm install webpack -g

# Install db-migrate
RUN npm install db-migrate@0.11.11 -g

# Set up a WORKDIR for application in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

# npm install to create node_modules in the container
RUN npm install

# EXPOSE your server port
EXPOSE 3000
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  csps-lint:
    image: <<my image>>
    container_name: csps-lint
    ports:
      - '3002:3002'
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test
      - LINT_COMMAND=${LINT_COMMAND}
    command: npm run ${LINT_COMMAND}
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

And this is the bash script that is running the ESLint command:

```bash
  # Run Prettier in check mode and store status
  echo -e "\033[1;33mRunning Prettier to identify code formatting issues...\033[0m\n"
  prettier --check .
  PRETTIER_STATUS=$?

  # Run ESLint in check mode and store status
  echo -e "\n\033[1;33mRunning ESLint to identify code quality issues...\033[0m"
  npx eslint .
  ESLINT_STATUS=$?
```

I have tried adding the recommended fix from the error message in multiple places, but nothing seems to resolve the issue.  I've put this command in the `lint.sh` script, I've added it to the `Dockerfile`, I've tried adding in the `docker-compose` file as well, but I'm unable to resolve the issue no matter where I place the command.

```
sudo chown -R 1001:123 "/root/.npm"
```

In a few of the instances, there was no access to `sudo`, so I'm wondering if I somehow need to install that first?  Do I even need to be setting these permissions?  Is there something that has changed from Node v14 to Node v16 that I'm just overlooking?

I've tried to use the solutions provided in other posts with similar error messages for other packages, but none of the solutions seem to fix this issue.

I feel like there must just be some very small thing I've missed, but the part that I'm really lost on is that I haven't changed this workflow other than upgrading the Node.js version in the Dockerfile.  Also, I am able to run this workflow locally without issue in a container created from the same image, but inside GH Actions I can't seem to get past this flow.

When running the following command locally `docker exec csps-lint ls -la /root/.npm/_logs`, this is my output:

```bash
total 1080
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Dec  2 23:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Dec  2 20:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1589 Nov 15 06:46 2022-11-15T06_46_44_197Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1589 Dec  2 20:15 2022-12-02T20_15_05_450Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  65102 Dec  2 20:15 2022-12-02T20_15_05_684Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  59037 Dec  2 20:15 2022-12-02T20_15_09_141Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 943351 Dec  2 20:15 2022-12-02T20_15_14_433Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1706 Dec  2 20:23 2022-12-02T20_23_05_075Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1756 Dec  2 20:23 2022-12-02T20_23_16_787Z-debug-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1599 Dec  2 23:02 2022-12-02T23_02_23_793Z-debug-0.log
```

**UPDATE:** So I have discovered that when I run the script in the csps-lint folder locally, the user is `root`, but when it is run in the CI/CD, it runs as an unnamed user with ID 1001.  I'm really unclear why the user would be different when the container is built from the same image no matter where it's being run.

Comment: Try adding the line `RUN chown -R 1001:123 "/root/.npm"` to the end of your Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @ManishDash.  I did give this a go and while it did change the permissions to 1001:123 in that folder, the error still persists in GitHub Actions, unfortunately.  It even still says to run the same command to fix it...

Answer (score 3):

I believe this issue was caused by npm updates no longer running in `root`.  After much back and forth and trying 101 different things, I was able to resolve the issue by:

1. Adding the following command to the end of my dockerfile

   ```
   RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/app
   ```
2. Adding a `user` key to my docker-compose.yml file

   ```yaml
   version: '3'
   services:
     csps-lint:
       image: <<my image>>
       user: node
       container_name: csps-lint
       ports:
         - '3002:3002'
       volumes:
         - ./:/usr/src/app
         - node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
       environment:
         - NODE_ENV=test
         - LINT_COMMAND=${LINT_COMMAND}
       command: npm run ${LINT_COMMAND}
   volumes:
     node_modules:
   ```